# Acumatica REST API - StockItem - How to use UOMConversions from response

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

In Acumatica REST API - StockItem

I am using the url https://sandbox.kimballinc.com/AcumaticaERP/entity/Default/18.200.001/StockItem?$filter=InventoryID eq '12345' & $expand=UOMConversions

In the response i am getting UOMConversions object as 
        "UOMConversions": [
            {
                "rowNumber": 1,
                "note": null,
                "ConversionFactor": {
                    "value": 1
                },
                "FromUOM": {
                    "value": "EACH"
                },
                "MultiplyDivide": {
                    "value": "Multiply"
                },
                "ToUOM": {
                    "value": "FOOT"
                }
             }
        ]

I want to know how ConversionFactor, FromUOM, MultiplyDivide, ToUOM is used and possible values for these fields.
can you please help me in understand these fields. Thanks

Comment: Should be covered in distribution training documents: https://openuni.acumatica.com/courses/distribution/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to find more information on that , I would recommend that you connect to the Acumatica site in the browser, Navigate to the Stock Item screen and go to the help page for that screen(Tools -> Help).
Once on the help screen, search for the "**Unit Conversion Table**" you will then find more information about these fields.

For the values that are available, I would recommend once again to go to the browser and the screen itself. Open the selector for the "**From Unit**" field and the drop-down for the "**Multiply/Divid**" field. The "**Conversion**" being just a decimal number and the "**To Unit**" being a read only field that take for value the base unit of the Stock Item.

Comment: Is it inside sandbox login - https://sandbox.kimballinc.com/AcumaticaERP or inside inside acumatica partner portal - https://portal.acumatica.com ?

Comment: If you're looking for help page it's: https://help-2019r1.acumatica.com/(W(2))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=73b4272d-aab3-4056-ab90-9ae59037275d